# When I add window.location.hash my div element goes behind top nav bar

Tags: javascript, window.location

window.location.hash = '#login-control';
When I add window.location.hash on my div element login-control goes behind top nav bar.
I want to display it after my top bar but half of login-box portion goes behind sticky top nav bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the [Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) of that div element in your CSS

It should be higher than your top nav bar.

Comment: zindex do nothing.when I add top:162px it comes after navbar but leave top space  on page.how can I fixed this @Yogesh Kotadiya

Comment: fixed it by using window.scroll(0,370);